# Please check grammar and structure!

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

The bar chart presents the number of male and female who did regular activity in Australia in 2010. The information,according six different age groups by gender,are illustrated in percentage.

Comment: Please check requirements for acceptable questions!

Comment: We don't do proofreading, but I have to say your sentences are all over the place. Male and female what? Or do you mean men and women or perhaps men and boys women and girls? Males and females might work or both *genders* depending on the preceeding context which you have not provided. According *to* might make some sense. Please put spaces after commas.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying to say. My edits are in caps:

The bar chart presents the number of maleS and femaleS who did regular activity in Australia in 2010. The information, CATEGORIZED according TO six different age groups by gender, is REPORTED (USE 'REPORTED' INSTEAD OF ILLUSTRATED?) in percentages.

Comment: Much better, but could still be improved.

Comment: I wanted to leave the original structure as unchanged as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!